# Function which relies on workspace and memory

Tags: matlab, function, memory, workspace

I have a function which gets its inputs from a `.mat` file. This works just fine, but recently I had to update those variables and they increased by orders of magnitude in number. Therefore, the loading time increased.

Since the function is iterated `10 000` times this is a major problem now. You may ask, why do you load those workspace variables in the first place? The answer to this is that I import variables that may change from time to time which I save conveniently as workspace before calling the function. The previous code had those variables written in the script similar to `a=1` `b=4` etc., which only works if the user accesses the code which I rather avoid.

So the question is, how can I access those variables elegantly in a function?

```
function 
    load vars.mat
    execute statements ...
end
```

or

```
function 
    global vars
    execute statements
end
```

seem to be a much, much slower variant of

```
function
    a=1
    b=4 
    ...
    execute statements
end
```

Comment: why not make those variables global and load them once per execution?

Comment: Hi and thank you very much for your contribution. I did that :) but it still is slower than the script form, and please dont ask why. Maybe it eats more memory to have stuff in the workspace than having it in a script which is executed all over multiple times?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly, but is the number of variables fixed? It might be possible to write a file of the form:
callerfunction(),
load workspace.mat,
[output] = actualfunction(variables)
but of course, this only works if the variables stay the same or you'd have to alter the 'variables' argument of the actualfunction

Comment: yes they stay the same and never change. in functions loading them once and then working with them should be ok, since then no further operations are required. HOWEVER, when i call fsolve, this one doesnt accept the global variables I defined earlier. Overall it is somewhat slower and I cant exactly figure out why.  Could you give me a concrete example of your callerfunction so I can try your solution first?